# Отправка базы данных на почту или загрузка в txt

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmyadmin

Пытаюсь по нажатию на кпопку сделать отправку базы данных на почту, но в итоге приходит некоректное письмо!

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../loadtxt.php',
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                console.log('good');
 
             },
             error:function(respond){
                console.log('bad');
             }
        });
});

//PHP

<?php

 
  $connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)
  or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
 
  mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)
  or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$c = true;

 $ss = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM commenduser");
 echo json_encode($ss);
while ($d = mysql_fetch_array($ss)){
//гененрируем письмо
$subject = "Коментарии"; 
$from = "xxx@gmail.com";
$to = "xxx@gmail.com";
$message ="Сообщения"; 

$boundary = "--".md5(uniqid(time())); 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0;\r\n"; 
$headers .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: info@site.ru ";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\";" . "\r\n";

$arr = mysql_fetch_array($ss);


foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
        $multipart .= "
        " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}

mail($to,$subject,$multipart,$headers);
 }
?>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>send</button>
```

В итоге на почте получаю такое:

```
 <tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>id</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>5c63eba6bc584</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>1</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>type</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>2</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>test</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>name</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>test</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>3</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>test@mail.com</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>mail</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>test@mail.com</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>4</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>28834734</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>phone</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>28834734</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>5</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>rating</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>6</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>commend</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>commend</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>commend</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: А зачем вызывать `mysql_fetch_array` два раза? И кстати - почему вы используете расширение `mysql` которое уже устарело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это псевдокод на основании твоего, проверь, если не работает как надо покажи print_r($arr); и переведи код на mysqli_query (лучше pdo)

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../loadtxt.php',
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                console.log('good');

             },
             error:function(respond){
                console.log('bad');
             }
        });
});


  $connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)
  or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

  mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)
  or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$c = true;

 $ss = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM commenduser");
 echo json_encode($ss);

$multipart = '';
foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
        $multipart .= "
        " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}

unset($key,$value);

//гененрируем письмо
$subject = "Коментарии"; 
$from = "xxx@gmail.com";
$to = "xxx@gmail.com";
$message ="Сообщения"; 

$boundary = "--".md5(uniqid(time())); 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0;\r\n"; 
$headers .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: info@site.ru ";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\";" . "\r\n";
//------------------

mail($to,$subject,$multipart,$headers);//тут отправит таблицу
```